# Struct with static variables vs class with static variables vs class-based singleton vs global vars

Tags: swift

If I want a global type to hold my environment configurations (urls and such), what's the best way to create a single instance? I dynamically change my base urls. What's the functional difference between doing this:

```
struct AppEnvironment {
    static var baseUrl = "prod.stackoverflow.com" // test, staging, etc.
}
```

and this

```
class AppEnvironment {
  static var baseUrl = "prod.stackoverflow.com"
}
```

and this

```
class AppEnvironmentSingleton {
  private init()
  static let shared = AppEnvironment()
  var baseUrl = "prod.stackoverflow.com"
}
```

Calling `[singleton/type].baseUrl = "newValue"` yields the same result, why should I use one over the other?

Comment: And what about a global `var`? You forgot that possibility.

Comment: Or keeping it in UserDefaults?

Comment: I forgot to include global vars because I was thinking of grouping other environment code in the same container, but that is also a valid approach. UserDefaults seem like a good idea except I make a lot of network calls, wouldn't getting the value everytime incur an overhead?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the difference of class vs struct i recommend some basic reading about [structs and classes](https://learnappmaking.com/struct-vs-class-swift-how-to/)

A singleton in this context would only be necessary if you actually need an instance of your class/struct. But from your post i don't think this is necessary here.

While i am in no means a swift developer this [Article](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/let-s-setup-your-ios-environments) describes a very nifty way to define and use different environments that could suit you pretty well. :)